# How to build Treeview from XML?

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, restsharp

I'm trying to populate a Treeview using the returned data from a web service call.  I have used Restsharp to make the call and return the data.  However, I'm really struggling to figure out how to pass it into a proper treeview.  I've been trying to use [this CodeProject guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/447349/Populate-TreeView-from-Simple-list) - but I have not been able to get it to work and I've created a mess of my code trying to adapt that.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

The XML is returned as:

```
    <ListItems xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Items>
    <ListItem>
      <ID>n0z5tVQXsbTgB8PUp7tE5$p5shhQOV3s5Y</ID>
      <URI>https://URL/n0z5tVQXsbTgB8PUp7tE5$p5shhQOV3s5Y</URI>
      <ListID>nnK2NXzfmoCyTPE0yck44Nswy1Ho964Lo</ListID><Name>BATMAN</Name><ParentID xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level1Code>BATMAN</Level1Code><Level2Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level3Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level4Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level5Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level6Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level7Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level8Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level9Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level10Code xsi:nil="true" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <ID>n0z5tVQXsbTnByah$pfDj0gDjm$sMYSfFYB</ID>
      <URI>https://URL/n0z5tVQXsbTnByah$pfDj0gDjm$sMYSfFYB</URI>
      <ListID>nnK2NXzfmoCyTPE0yck44Nswy1Ho964Lo</ListID><Name>Rig Move Project Management</Name>
      <ParentID>n0z5tVQXsbTgB8PUp7tE5$p5shhQOV3s5Y</ParentID><Level1Code>BATMAN</Level1Code>
      <Level2Code>RMPM</Level2Code><Level3Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level4Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level5Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level6Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level7Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level8Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level9Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level10Code xsi:nil="true" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <ID>n0z5tVQXsbT76YjU9r5rbMbo526tKB7kT</ID>
      <URI>https://URL/n0z5tVQXsbT76YjU9r5rbMbo526tKB7kT</URI>
      <ListID>nnK2NXzfmoCyTPE0yck44Nswy1Ho964Lo</ListID><Name>14-RMPM-AUG</Name>
      <ParentID>n0z5tVQXsbTnByah$pfDj0gDjm$sMYSfFYB</ParentID><Level1Code>BATMAN</Level1Code>
      <Level2Code>RMPM</Level2Code><Level3Code>14-RMPM-AUG</Level3Code><Level4Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level5Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level6Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level7Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level8Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level9Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level10Code xsi:nil="true" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <ID>n0z5tVQXsbT98mCa24ijg8oKVUXUu9voE</ID>
      <URI>https://URL/n0z5tVQXsbT98mCa24ijg8oKVUXUu9voE</URI>
      <ListID>nnK2NXzfmoCyTPE0yck44Nswy1Ho964Lo</ListID><Name>14-RMPM-SEP</Name>
      <ParentID>n0z5tVQXsbTnByah$pfDj0gDjm$sMYSfFYB</ParentID><Level1Code>BATMAN</Level1Code>
      <Level2Code>RMPM</Level2Code><Level3Code>14-RMPM-SEP</Level3Code><Level4Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level5Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level6Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level7Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level8Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level9Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level10Code xsi:nil="true" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <ID>n0z5tVQXsbTzkVY2DmlIKqTJQ$ssiU$sZhq</ID>
      <URI>https://URL/n0z5tVQXsbTzkVY2DmlIKqTJQ$ssiU$sZhq</URI>
      <ListID>nnK2NXzfmoCyTPE0yck44Nswy1Ho964Lo</ListID><Name>14-RMPM-DEC</Name>
      <ParentID>n0z5tVQXsbTnByah$pfDj0gDjm$sMYSfFYB</ParentID><Level1Code>BATMAN</Level1Code>
      <Level2Code>RMPM</Level2Code><Level3Code>14-RMPM-DEC</Level3Code><Level4Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level5Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level6Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level7Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level8Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level9Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level10Code xsi:nil="true" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <ID>n0z5tVQXsbT3akVrmqiTRzuqyw4bvZhNj</ID>
      <URI>https://URL/n0z5tVQXsbT3akVrmqiTRzuqyw4bvZhNj</URI>
      <ListID>nnK2NXzfmoCyTPE0yck44Nswy1Ho964Lo</ListID><Name>BOONE</Name><ParentID xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level1Code>BOONE</Level1Code><Level2Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level3Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level4Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level5Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level6Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level7Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level8Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level9Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level10Code xsi:nil="true" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <ID>n0z5tVQXsbTJzA$pdmVRdjjTNL8ZgV2CtV</ID>
      <URI>https://URL/n0z5tVQXsbTJzA$pdmVRdjjTNL8ZgV2CtV</URI>
      <ListID>nnK2NXzfmoCyTPE0yck44Nswy1Ho964Lo</ListID><Name>TEST</Name>
      <ParentID>n0z5tVQXsbT3akVrmqiTRzuqyw4bvZhNj</ParentID><Level1Code>BOONE</Level1Code><Level2Code>TEST</Level2Code>
      <Level3Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level4Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level5Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level6Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level7Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level8Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level9Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level10Code xsi:nil="true" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <ID>n0z5tVQXsbTJzA$pdmVRdjjTNL8ZgV2CtV</ID>
      <URI>https://URL/n0z5tVQXsbTJzA$pdmVRdjjTNL8ZgV2CtV</URI>
      <ListID>nnK2NXzfmoCyTPE0yck44Nswy1Ho964Lo</ListID><Name>TEST1</Name>
      <ParentID>n0z5tVQXsbT3akVrmqiTRzuqyw4bvZhNj</ParentID><Level1Code>BOONE</Level1Code><Level2Code>TEST1</Level2Code>
      <Level3Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level4Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level5Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level6Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level7Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level8Code xsi:nil="true" />
      <Level9Code xsi:nil="true" /><Level10Code xsi:nil="true" />
    </ListItem>
  </Items>
  <NextPage xsi:nil="true" />
</ListItems>
```

So it should work out to:

-BATMAN
---RMPM
------14-RMPM-AUG
------14-RMPM-SEP
------14-RMPM-DEC
-BOONE
---TEST
---TEST1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is take your xml and use the `Paste Special -> Paste XML As Class` feature of VS 2013 to create the class from the XML.  Then I use the XML serializer to deserialize the XML into an object I can use.   Then I created tree nodes for each of the items and built up the appropriate structure and added the roots to the Tree View.

It makes a few assumptions:

- Id is unique ( I had to massage the second test node for this)
- Name is what you want to use for the tree text
- Parent node is created before the child node

---

```
string xml = ""; // Your big XML string
StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListItems));
ListItems listItems = (ListItems)xs.Deserialize(sr);
Dictionary<string, TreeNode> nodes = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();

foreach (var item in listItems.Items)
{
    TreeNode node;
    nodes.Add(item.ID, node = new TreeNode(item.Name));
    if (item.ParentId != null)
        nodes[item.ParentId].Nodes.Add(node);
    else
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
}
/* Edited this out, can do in only one loop
foreach (var item in listItems.Items)
{
    var children = from i in listItems.Items where i.ParentID == item.ID select i;

    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        nodes[item.ID].Nodes.Add(nodes[child.ID]);
    }

    if (item.ParentID==null)
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(nodes[item.ID]);
}
*/
```

Comment: Thank you, John.  The Id is unique - I copied/pasted the second test node just for example's sake and forgot to change that.  I'm getting ready to leave the office so will have to test this tonight when I get home, but at first glance it looks very clear, straightforward, and (hopefully) exactly what I need.

Comment: Seems like each parent is created before the child node, so you don't need the second (and inner) `foreach` loop. Use the item's ParentId to get the parent's node. Edited post since didn't want to copy your serialization.

Comment: Provided that that assumption is true for all data, then yes.

Comment: I created the new classes using the Paste XML As Class, then used the same code you gave, but I'm getting a "Argument type 'System.Type' is not assignable to parameter type 'string'" on the XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListItems));" line ?

Comment: Apparently the issue was with Restsharp's XmlSerializer.  I changed the line to read `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof (ListItems));` and now it works great.  Thanks again, John! And thank you, Chuck, for your simplification - my case WILL always have the parent created before the child.